# Type or namespace could not be found -- Unity 3d Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've built a custom .dll that I want to integrate into a unity project. I added the .dll to the reference folder and I get no errors from Visual Studio; however, Unity Editor keeps giving me an error that the Type or namespace of my custome .dll can not be found.

Any help?

Comment: Did you put it into _Assets/Plugins_ ? s. [Building Plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html)

Comment: @Kay yes I did...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any .NET feature in your managed plugin (.dll) which is not supported by Unity3D (features from .NET versions greater than .NET 2.0), It may compile alright in Visual Studio/Mono, but would throw compiler error in Unity3D. [Read more...](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html)

AND

As @Kay mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647767/type-or-namespace-could-not-be-found-unity-3d-editor#comment66599299_39647767), any *Native* or *Managed* plugin files must be placed in **/Plugins** folder in platform specific sub-folder.

NOTE: *Plugins* can be placed anywhere under *Assets* folder.

Hope this helps